# Jquery - change cursor for objects with z-index <= 0

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a possibility to change the `css-cursor` attribute for all objects of a specific group (images), if their `z-index` is `<= 0`?
I'm not sure if this can be done without a loop.

Maybe with just using selectors.
It would be nice if you can give me a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with this approach as it lowers the "startup" processing and only applies the cursor if the mouse enters the image.

```
$('img').mouseenter(
    function(ev){
        if($(this).css('z-index') <= 0) 
        {            
            $(this).css('cursor', 'move');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse all your element and test if your requirement is met. Then apply your rule.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').each(function(){
        if($(this).css('z-index') <= 0) 
        {
            //Change CSS cursor attribute
            $(this).css('cursor','move');
        }
    });
});
```